# How to set auto incremented Id column in jQuery tables while using render method

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery Datatable like below

```
 let purchasedProductTbl = $('#grdPurchasedProduct').DataTable({
            filter: false,
            paging: false,
            lengthChange: false,
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            autoWidth: false,
                language: {
                    paginate: {
                        next: '&#8594;', // or '→'
                        previous: '&#8592;' // or '←'
                    },
                    emptyTable: "No data available.."
                },
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        "defaultContent": "-",
                        "targets": "_all"
                    }
                ],
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "active",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        console.log(row)
                        console.log(data)
                        console.log(row().index())
                        if (type === 'display') {
                            return '<div class="ckbox"><input type="checkbox" style="width:15px"; id=childCheckbox' + row.id + '><label for="childCheckbox' + row.id + '"></label></div>'
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    className: "dt-body-center"
                },

                   {
                        "render": function (d, t, r) {
                            let $select = $("<input type='text' class='product-unit' disabled/>", {
                                "id": r[0] + "start",
                                "value": d
                            });

                            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        }
                    }

                ]
        });
```

In this example the first column is a `checkbox`. I have used a `label` for style it differently, based on my style when the `checkbox` id match with the `label-for` attribute then it will work like a `checkbox`. My issue is I have many columns in this grid all dynamically generated so I am not getting any `unique` number for differentiating each `checkboxes`. Is there anyway to give a `unique` id or auto generated id for this kind of columns ?

I have tried to get the row number but here row itself is coming as empty array.

Is there any other option to get the `row number` or some other `unique` numbers for each row render method ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [make use](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) of `meta` argument of `render` callback. It has row index as a property:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ...
    columns: [{
        title: 'id',
        data: null,
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => meta.row
    },
    //the rest of your column definitions
    ...
    ]
})
```

Comment: the call back will get fired only after the render right ? I need to create my dynamic controls in render method , not after that.

Comment: Id's will be added **right at the moment** each particular cell is rendered. You should try that out to see yourself.

Comment: ow really , that should be cool then , I will check it today and let u back. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

> Update : 07/04/2019

We can make use of [meta](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) argument of render callback. It has row index as a property

```
  render: function (data, type, row,meta) {
//console.log(meta)
}
```

> Another approach

so I have used the function below to get a random number

```
function uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}
```

And then used the same in my `datatable` like below

```
 {
                    data: "active",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var uniqueId = uuidv4();
                        if (type === 'display') {
                            return '<div class="ckbox"><input type="checkbox" style="width:15px"; id=childCheckbox' + uniqueId + '><label for="childCheckbox' + uniqueId + '"></label></div>'
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    className: "dt-body-center"
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get as below,

```
   var t = $('#grdPurchasedProduct').DataTable({ ....... });



        t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
            t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            } );
        } ).draw();
```

Or you want at render time then you can simply get

```
        {"render": function (data, type,full, row) {
            console.log(row.row);
            return '';
        }}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this one I saw in the datatable documentation but not sure about how can i use the same in my situation. Do you have any idea ?Because I basically need the unique id at the time of rendering, there is no use of getting the id after rendering

Comment: You want to display in datatable ? Please post final usage

Comment: {"render": function (data, type,full, row) {
            console.log(row.row);
            return '';
        }}

Comment: row itself is null , so row.row is always undefined

Comment: i dont want to display it in datatable instead i need to generate dynamic controls which has unique ids

Comment: why its null ? its should have data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195016/discussion-between-mak-and-arunprasanth-k-v).

Comment: why it cant be null ? I am not using server side processing and i dont even have a json data in client side also , i am just creating an empty row using  purchasedProductTbl.row.add([]).draw(false); so row will be null i guess